# Index error while working with sys argv in PyCharm

Tags: python, sys

I'm using 'sys' module to get the filename as an argument in the command line while I'm running the script in cmd it is working as I want, but if I run this in PyCharm it raises an error `Index Error: list index out of range`. How to get rid of this error in PyCharm?
Here is the Code I'm trying to run:

```
import sys
def read_lines(file):
    list_of_numbers = []
    with open(file, mode='r') as read_file:
        for number in read_file:
            number = number.strip()
            list_of_numbers.append(number)
    return list_of_numbers
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun = read_lines(sys.argv[1])
    print(fun)
```

While running the script directly from pycharm it raises following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProjects\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    fun = read_lines(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I think u don't have any data in sys.argv list, first print the sys.argv list before rad_lines function

Comment: @NoumanAkram sys.argv will get the filename on runtime, so how can I go for defining the parameter before? I'll be grateful if you can write the code for me.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably that's because you don't provide any arguments when running the script in PyCharm.

You can run the following script to print all the arguments:

```py
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
```

If you run it in the command line something like this

```
python3 test.py filename.txt
```

You should the output

```py
['test.py', 'filename.txt']
```

(the first argument is the name of your script).
In PyCharm, you also have to specify `filename.txt` as a parameter.
Otherwise, you only get

```py
['test.py']
```

which means that there is no element 1, hence the `IndexError`.

You can fix it by adding the `filename.txt` parameter to your run configuration in PyCharm.

Comment: how can I specify the file name in PyCharm while the function read_line() only accepts one argument? Can you please write me the code for that?

Comment: Your code is okay. The problem is that when the code gets used, it needs to get passed an extra parameter. In the command line, you explicitly state the parameter (`filename.txt` in the example). But PyCharm does not know about it, so you have to configure it. In other words, PyCharm does not know what file you want to open.
You could work around the whole thing by replacing line 10 with `fun = read_lines('filename.txt')`

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in that case, it will only work for PyCharm and will not accept the argv using the command line. I want to make it work for the command line and PyCharm as well.